# List all links present in a given website

Tags: hyperlink, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'd need a suggestion on the most effective way to list all links in a website. I am able to do it with either php vb and I have tried to do it with scrapy, but my problem is that with the first 2 it is not enough inputting the address of the website, I actually have to scrape the following links in my code, and with scrapy I have tried to list all susequent links in the page, but the spider seems never ending the research.

In otehr words I'd need to find out a way to input a website adress returning all links present in that website. I'd need to do that for a school project and I was thinking to do a small research on the retailing industry so I'd need to list up to 20 000 results for a given website.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scrapy` is a perfect choice here. Use [`CrawlSpider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) with [`LinkExtractor`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#topics-link-extractors).

The following spider would `follow` and gather all links on the website. Since there is an [`OffsiteMiddleware`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.spidermiddleware.offsite) enabled by default - you would not get links from other domains.

```
from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class SampleItem(Item):
    link = Field()


class SampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "sample_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://domain.com"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_page(self, response):
        item = SampleItem()
        item['link'] = response.url
        return item
```

If you want to limit the number of links and stop the spider after getting n links, use [`Close Spider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.contrib.closespider) extension and set [`CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#std:setting-CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT) setting:

> CLOSESPIDER_ITEMCOUNT
>
> An integer which specifies a number of items. If the spider scrapes
>   more than that amount if items and those items are passed by the item
>   pipeline, the spider will be closed with the reason
>   closespider_itemcount. If zero (or non set), spiders won’t be closed
>   by number of passed items.

In your case you can also use [`CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-pagecount) setting instead.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint!!
2 Further questions :
If I'd need to list the pages containing only a certain string would it be possible? So that I'd be able to list only the products pages and not the main page for example. 
Would it be possible to perform it on more than one site at a time?

Comment: @markoc. yeah, it would be possible. Consider asking a separate question so that more people have a chance to help you with it. Throw me a link here too. If the following topic is resolved, don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I will post the new questions. At the moment I tried the scrapy spider you posted but I get an error "cannot export LinkExtractor". any idea?? I am a real beginner with scrapy but it seems resourcefull ! thanks again – here it is the link to my new issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788376/scrapy-error-cannot-import-name-link-extractor

Comment: -> one related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24805425/scrapy-crawl-only-part-of-a-website . Thanks again!