# Scrapy crawl only part of a website

Tags: python, hyperlink, scrapy, web-crawler

Hello there I have the following code to scan all links in a give site.

```
from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class SampleItem(Item):
    link = Field()


class SampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "sample_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://domain.com"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_page(self, response):
        item = SampleItem()
        item['link'] = response.url
        return item
```

If I'like to check only part of a global site how could I do it? I have tried for example to scan only the french part of an international site whose domain is structured as : domain.com/fr/fr. So I have tried doing :

```
from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class SampleItem(Item):
    link = Field()


class SampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "sample_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com/fr/fr"]
    start_urls = ["http://domain.com/fr/fr"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_page(self, response):
        item = SampleItem()
        item['link'] = response.url
        return item
```

But the spider only returns 3 results instead of thousands. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To crawl only part of a website, you have to use the LinkExtractor. You can get a sample by issueing `scrapy genspider -t crawl domain domain.com`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from test.items import testItem


class DomainSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'domain'
    allowed_domains = ['domain.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.domain.com/fr/fr']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'fr/'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        i = testItem()
        #i['domain_id'] = response.xpath('//input[@id="sid"]/@value').extract()
        #i['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="name"]').extract()
        #i['description'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="description"]').extract()
        return i
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot! I tried it but I get an error message "Import error: No module named items". Any idea?

Comment: Yep, you need an items.py file. Two tips: 1) RTFM :-) 2) use the scrapy command line tool to generate projects and spiders, it will make sure you have all the folders and files you need, as well as give you examples.

Comment: All though I have already an Items file in my project called "items" and contained in my project folder the one containint the spiders folder. Here it is the code inside the items.py. It was created by using the command line tool "scrapy startproject ..."

Comment: If you have a file at myproject/myproject/items.py, you can import it with `from myproject.items import MyItem`. Capitalization matters, so make sure you have correctly spelled the item class name, etc.

Comment: does this crawl everything there is under fr/ example fr/test/myside.php or is it only fr/ there been crawled ?